# Mysql access over LAN

Tags: mysql, database, java, remote-access

I have created a java application which connects to a mysql database using the **JDBC driver**. I have the mysql server running on the same machine as my java application.

When I connect to the database on localhost the application is working fine. My system in connected to other systems via LAN. Now i want to run my application on these systems connecting to the database on the mysql server i have on my system.

What changes do i need to make in my **mysql workbench** or the **java application** to deploy this. I have mysql 6.1 workbench installed.

I am getting the following error:

```
run: Communications link failure

 Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago. Exception in thread
 "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
         at help.helpdesk.Ready(helpdesk.java:97)
         at help.helpdesk.<init>(helpdesk.java:89)
         at help.helpdesk$6.run(helpdesk.java:428)
         at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
         at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122) BUILD
 SUCCESSFUL (total time: 22 seconds)
```

when I try to connect to the database on my local server by using the ip address of my system.

Comment: check ya firewall.  Also try to telnet to to remoteHost:3306

Comment: Check your connection properties in JDBC and not bad to show code.

Comment: can you bind the ip address?

Comment: @disable1992 my JDBC is working fine because i tried the application with the localhost address as the **String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";** and it was working fine..

Comment: @ScaryWombat how should i check if my firewall is causing the problem.

Comment: @AmitDubey i don't understand what are you trying to ask.

Comment: try to ping the host, or as I said before try to telnet to the host/port

Answer (score 4):

You need to do following changes

1.Edit the my.cnf

```
mysql/my.cnf
```

change the local ip

```
bind-address  = 192.168.1.2("your system ip")
```

2.restart the mysql server

and if you want connect to your database remotely than this [link](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/mysql-connect-to-your-database-remotely#Granting_Access) will helpful for you

Comment: @sky3287944 try /etc/mysql/my.cnf

Comment: sorry @sky3287944 i am using ubuntu,so i have no idea about my.cnf on window,but window mysql configuration may be path is C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.cnf

Comment: @sky3287944 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql similar question

Answer (score 4):

If you set bind-address = 0.0.0.0 in /etc/my.cnf, MySQL will be available across all interfaces both locally and over the network.